# magento htaccess gzip not working

Tags: .htaccess, magento, gzip

i have tried to enable gzip in magento but its not working
i followed some steps
like
enable 
`php_flag` `zlib.output_compression` `on`
than checked `phpinfo()` and the gzip shows enable than in my magento htacess i added code

but when i checked in gtmatrix or google pagespeed it ask for gzip compression

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

the above code was not working so i tried

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
Header set Content-Encoding x-deflate
# Header set Content-Encoding compress
# Header set Content-Encoding x-gzip
</filesMatch>
```

but when i added this my css and js stopped working what should i do to enable it?

Comment: have you tried restarting apache??

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable from server? please check that extentions

Answer (score 0):

Add this Code in your .htaccess file in order to enable gzip compression -

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>
```